# Using dynamicaly updated excel data in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have written a script to read data from an excel sheet.  The values in the sheet are dynamic, changing every minute or so.  How can I have my script rerun using the refreshed data?  Now my workaround is very manual.  (1)save the excel file and then (2) rerun the script. I'm not sure how to automate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doubt you'll be able to read the file without saving it. Add a VBA macro that saves it every 30s or so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the excel file another way, but you can watch if the file changes by using this script:

```
import os, time

def run():
    ...

path = "/path/to/excel/file"

old_mod_time = os.stat(path).st_mtime
run()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    mod_time = os.stat(path).st_mtime
    if mod_time != old_mod_time:
        run()
        old_mod_time = mod_time
```